# How to bind an Object to select in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object product{id,name} in reactjs es6. currently the SELECT only
accepts prod.name how could I assign prod.id, which is an integer, to 
select?
 p.s : es6 doenst allow me to assign integer to select.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
prod : product;
   };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
return(){
   <select value={prod.id} className="select-style" name="ProductId" onChange 
      {this.handleChange}>
      {this.props.store!.Product.map(product => <option key={product.id}> 
      {product.name}</option>)}
    </select>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found the answer, for assigning integer to select , I just needed to convert id to string

```
<select value={prod.id+''} className="select-style" name="pbxId" onChange 
  {this.handleChange}>
  {this.props.store!.Product.map(product => <option key={product.id}> 
  {product.name}</option>)}
</select>
```